# Transloadit: PDF to Video, variable length

Tags: pdf, video, heroku, transloadit

[/video/merge docs](https://transloadit.com/docs/conversion-robots/#video-merge)

I need a template that converts a PDF to a video. Unfortunately, the /video/merge robot seems to require both a framerate (slide length) *as well as* a video duration. Since I don't know how many pages the PDF will have, I'm unable to supply duration.

Is there a way around this?

This is a section of my current template:

```
"pdf_to_images": {
  "use": ":original",
  "robot": "/document/thumbs",
  "format": "png",
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080
},
"encode": {
  "use": {
    "steps": [
      {
        "name": "pdf_to_images",
        "as": "image"
      }
    ]
  },
  "robot": "/video/merge",
  "preset": "iphone",
  "width": 1920,
  "height": 1080,
  "ffmpeg": {
    "b": "8000K"
  },
  "framerate": "${fields.framerate}",
  "duration": "100"
},
//...store...
```

I need to replace "framerate" from a field in the upload, but can I replace "duration" from dynamically counting the number of results from "pdf_to_images"?

Otherwise I'm stuck creating individual videos from each image result from "pdf_to_images" and then concatenating them, which seems rather excessive in terms of resource capitalization.

Thoughts?

Comment: cant you count pages of pdf file and set duration = x*y where x is pages of pdf and y is time req for one page

Comment: The upload is using the Transloadit jQuery SDK, which means the upload bypasses my app altogether, going straight to Transloadit. I never even have the upload in hand to process.

Answer (score 0):

What you could be looking for is `${file.meta.page_count}` – which, as expected, will return the number of pages in the PDF from /document/thumbs. For example, if you wanted to make a video where each page of the PDF lasts a second you'd use a template like so:

```
{
  "steps": {
    ":original": {
      "robot": "/upload/handle"
    },
    "pdf_to_images": {
      "use": ":original",
      "robot": "/document/thumbs",
      "format": "png",
      "results": true,
      "width": 1920,
      "height": 1080,
      "imagemagick_stack": "v2.0.7"
    },
    "merged": {
      "robot": "/video/merge",
      "use": {
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "pdf_to_images",
            "as": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
      "result": true,
      "framerate": "1",
      "duration": "${file.meta.page_count}",
      "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1",
      "preset": "iphone",
      "resize_strategy": "fillcrop"
    }
  }
}
```